# How can I append value if NSAttributedstring contains external link?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

Hi I'm trying to get html from a website. It has internal and external links. How can I append string if link is external link. By the way internal links has `applewebdata://` and I check those ones as internal. But I couldn't understand how can I detect external links. I want just add something like that `»` .

Internal link href: `applewebdata://`
External link href contains `http://` or `https://`

[An example in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWXJW.jpg)

Comment: What's your definition of an external versus internal link? Update your question with some examples of both (the link URLs, not the text of the link).

Comment: Iterate the `NSAttributedString` looking for Link (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute), you can modify them if needed.

Comment: Define "I want just add something like that » ". You want that the link shown to user to be `önder ireveul »`, keep the link url and/or modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what you could do:
Enumerate the link attribute.
Check for each value if it's the one you want (the one that starts with "applewebdata://").
Modify either the rest of the string and/or the link (your question is unclear on that part, I made both).

`attributedString` needs to be mutable (`NSMutableAttributedString`).

```
attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.link, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), options: [.reverse]) { (attribute, range, pointee) in
    if let link = attribute as? URL, link.absoluteString.hasPrefix("applewebdata://") {
        var replacement = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: range))

        //Use replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with str: String) if you want to keep the same "effects" (attributes)
        replacement.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: replacement.length, length: 0), with: "~~>")

        //Change the link if needed
        let newLink = link.absoluteString + "2"
        replacement.addAttribute(.link, value: newLink, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: replacement.length))

        //Replace
        attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
    }
}
```

Code for Playground to put before if needed:

```
let htmlString = "Hello this <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">external link</a> and that's an <a href=\"applewebdata://myInternalLink\">internal link</a> and that's it."
let htmlData = htmlString.data(using: .utf8)!
let attributedString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData,
                                                      options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                                                      documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: I'm so so sorry about the late answer. It works very well! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

If the link is a `NSAttributedString`, you can just check if the value of the string contains `applewebdata://` or `http://`.

### Swift 4

In Swift 4, you can get the String from `NSAttributedString` with `.string` and a String is a collection of Character value:

```
let link = NSAttributedString(???) // Your LINK
let stringUrl = link.string
if stringUrl.contains("applewebdata") {
    // Do something to the internal link
} else if stringUrl.contains("http") {
    // Do something to the external link
}
```

Comment: But I cannot append value the just linked word. I'm trying to append string to link string.