# Change links colors and underline color of html converted to AttributedString

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I would like to color the links and give special color to the underline of the links in my text that received from html.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
...

public func htmlStyleAttributeText(text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {

        if let htmlData = text.data(using: .utf8) {

            let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]

            let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)

            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: AnyObject] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
            attributedString?.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString?.length ?? 0))
            return attributedString
        }

        return nil
    }
....
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What I am looking for is regular color for the text and red for the links and green for the underline of the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `UITextView`, it would be enough to set the `tintColor` to `UIColor.red` and remove the following:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: AnyObject] = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
attributedString?.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString?.length ?? 0))
```

so it would look like this:

```
public func htmlStyleAttributeText(text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    if let htmlData = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]
        let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        return attributedString
    }
    return nil
}

//
textView.tintColor = .red
textView.attributedText = htmlStyleAttributeText(text: "random text <a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com </a> more random text")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Omar, Can you please make the text black?

Comment: I got it! Red underline and black tintcolor

Comment: @Luda: How did you achieve a different underline and text color using the ‘tintColor’ property? That property should affect both colors...

Comment: @Mischa NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.red

Comment: Omar and @Mischa, It would be great if you could take a look at this question (which is in the same field) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279279/crashing-on-range-on-nstextstorage

Comment: @Luda: Then you’re not using the ‘tintColor’ because that’s an attribute, right?

Comment: @Mischa you can set the tint color in code like this: textView.tintColor = .black or in the storyboard.

Comment: I know how to set the tint color. I only want to make sure that other Stackoverflow users with the same problem as you find the correct answer and know what to do. Plus, I was also curious how this alternative solution might work. As you have marked this answer as the correct one, it should be clear for others what to do and for me, it just wasn't. Now – I believe – it is: You're using a combination of both answers.

Answer (score 5):

The color for the text is red because you set it to red for the entire attributed string:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: AnyObject] = 
                  [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
attributedString?.addAttributes(attributes, 
                  range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributedString?.length ?? 0))
```

If you want it to have a "regular" (= I guess black?) color, just don't do that and delete those lines.

And here's how to set the color for the links in your attributed string:
→ [Change the color of a link in an NSMutableAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28361072/2062785)

This is the key you'll need to use for setting a different underline color:
[NSAttributedString.Key.**underlineColor**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1528834-underlinecolor)

---

***Edit:***

To make it more explicit and put the pieces together — this is what you have to do in order to yield the desired link colors:

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
    .underlineColor: UIColor.red
]
```

(In addition to removing to two lines of code as stated above.)

Comment: But I do not know what is the range of the links?

Comment: @Luda I showed on another question how to get the .link ranges: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249765/how-can-i-append-value-if-nsattributedstring-contains-external-link/55259853#55259853

Comment: You don't need to. You just set the [link attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618632-linktextattributes) for your entire text view: `textView.linkTextAttributes = ...`.

Comment: It works. All underlines were colored in red. But the links text are still blue.

Comment: So is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Mischa black text, red underline

Comment: It’s all included in the other answer I linked above: You only have to set the respective color for the right attribute keys. For the underline color, you use the key ‘NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor’, for the font color, you use the key ‘NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor’. And then you assign those values to the property ‘linkTextAttributes’.

Comment: (See the additions to my answer above.)

Comment: Foreground color doesn't help. The link will stay blue. I needed to update the tint color to black and then it worked.

Comment: I have tested the above code. For me, it works exactly as described. The `foregroundColor` sets the color of the text itself. Maybe there is some other code in your project that overrides this attribute at some point?