# NSAttributed Text with a line along with some angle in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, line, nsattributedstring

I want to draw a strike through line in swift 4 as shown in below image.

[image]

I have drawn strike through line as shown in below image using followed code.

[image]

```
func strikeThrough(_ color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 1, range: textRange)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: 0, range: textRange)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.lightGray, range: textRange)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor, value: color, range: textRange)

    return attributeString
}
```

Any suggestions how do I draw the inclined line over text.
If possible give me a solution using Core Graphics.

Comment: You can use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403169-drawstrikethrough and a sample (for underline, but the logic on how to use it is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288142/getting-the-range-of-links-in-attributed-string/55288429#55288429), and customize it according to your needs

Answer (score 2):

Use UIBezierPath with your UILabel, let's name it label:

```
        var aPath = UIBezierPath()
        aPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: label.frame.origin.x , y:label.frame.origin.y  - 10)
        aPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width, y: label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height + 10))
        aPath.closePath()
        UIColor.redColor().set()
        aPath.stroke()
```

Feel free to play with origins of Points in order to get desired result. Also play with label.layer.addSublayer(aPath)

Comment: When we use frames it misbehaves when we rotate the screen.

Comment: The example above gives you an idea. No mention for rotate screen etc :) Anyway adding  as sublayer shall fix this issue. See updated response.